# I can't allocate memory for memory_limit

Tags: php

I try to import a large database. When I do import I get

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1088684032) (tried to allocate 539666662 bytes) in Z:\home\localhost\www\Tools\sqladmin\libraries\import.lib.php on line 340
```

I have set

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

everywhere I could: php.ini, phpmyadmin's config and even in `import.lib.php` at line 340 but keep getting this error.

Comment: @Dagon it is on local machine

Comment: How much RAM is still free on your machine when you launch the process?

Comment: @SolarBear I closed all my programs and left 6G free memory

Comment: Why are you using php for this? Why not look into `select into outfile` and `load data infile` via MySQL(?) directly?